# Add missing double quotes programmatically in Excel for csv file

Tags: excel, csv

I have a csv file with thousands of records that look like these two lines of the file:

```
TransferWise NZ "6400518"   "996467362814"  "Failed"    "P2569534"  "30/11/2019 9:54:27 PM" 
Growth Collective   "SS64007605"    "996467363128"  "Completed" "X255536"   "30/11/2019 10:07:49 PM"
```

When opened in Excel, each of these records takes up a single spreadsheet column.

The initial field (Company name) is missing double quotes. I really don't want to manually go through this file and add double quotes if I can avoid it. Is there a way this can be done programatically within Excel?

Data Screenshot:

[image]

**UPDATE: 2 complete lines from the file.**

```
The Growth Collective Limited   "SS64007605"    "996467363045" "Completed"  "my payee particulars|7uqh355g|355gkq2y|7uqh355gkq2y"   "30/11/2019 10:04:26 PM"    "30/11/2019 10:05:22 PM"    ""  "57.50" "ASB-P4-NZ" ""  "0199075"   "123216"    "00"    "True"  "MR P HUANG"    "4 "    "M" "MercoMGNZ" "Merco MGNZ"    "2" "LNDUXJJTHIWQYOXHUKHQAMETELHHMRHV"  "",,,,,,

2degrees Mobile Limited "6400910"   "996467332367"  "Completed" "|POLIPRE|220181318|"   "30/11/2019 7:04:02 AM" "30/11/2019 7:04:58 AM" "16053" "20.00" "Westpac-P4-NZ" ""  "0289335"   "030866"    "000"   "True"  ""  "4 "    "M" "MercoMGNZ" "Merco MGNZ"    "2" "220181318 POLIPRE MobileApp 1-9YH-3304"    "",,,,,,
```

Comment: So your final goal is to see all the data in Excel distributed to proper columns? Because now it seems that you want to correct the csv file itself. But you need the Excel version, right?

Comment: All I want to do is add double quotes around the first field for every record including the header record. These are missing. I want to use Excel to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you have quite a lot of data. This approach will read all your cells in range "A" into an array while adding the quotes, then print the array to the range. Make sure to backup your data before attempting in case the unexpected happens. Please also note this will throw an error when encountering empty cells, or cells without a `"` in it (indicating there is only one column). Also this will all be posted to column B, as to not overwrite your data, you can move this to column A when you wish.

```
Sub adquote()
Dim cel As Long
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim lastr As Long

lastr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ReDim arr(1 To lastr)

For cel = 1 To lastr
    arr(cel) = """" & Left(Range("A" & cel).Value, InStr(Range("A" & cel).Value, """")) & """" & Right(Range("A" & cel).Value, Len(Range("A" & cel).Value) - InStr(Range("A" & cel).Value, """"))
Next cel

Range("B1:B" & lastr).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
End Sub
```

As you state you have some trouble to get this version working, perhaps the one without an array will do the trick:

```
Sub adquote()
Dim cel As Long
Dim lastr As Long

lastr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For cel = 1 To lastr
    Range("B" & cel).value = """" & Left(Range("A" & cel).Value, InStr(Range("A" & cel).Value, """")) & """" & Right(Range("A" & cel).Value, Len(Range("A" & cel).Value) - InStr(Range("A" & cel).Value, """"))
Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: THanks Plutian, where do I insert that code in order to make it happen?

Comment: Ah sorry, this is VBA code. You press `(left)ALT + F11`, which will bring up the VB window. Then click `insert` in the top menu, and select `module`. In the newly created screen, paste this code and press `F5`. Make sure to backup first as I stated, to account for unexpected results.

Comment: I get "Runtime error '13' Type mismatch" at the line "Range("A1:A" & lastr).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)"

Comment: Interesting, the code should run as expected and return strings, there's no alternate types going on. Are you sure you copied the code as-is, and didn't miss out anything?  Can I ask, is there anything in column "A" to begin with? If not, you could get this error.

Comment: Is there any way you could post a screenshot of your data, and show me how it's formatted?

Comment: Screenshot here: https://snipboard.io/sOvC5u.jpg. I wonder if the header row is causing the issues

Comment: Ah I see the problem, it seems I misunderstood your question, and assumed the columns were populated as necessary. No problem, I'll revise my answer if you give me a moment, it'll be a bit more tricky this way but far from impossible.

Comment: I have updated my answer, this will now search for the `"` character in the cells contents, then compose the following string: `"` and `part to first "` and `"` and `part after first"`

Comment: Thanks Plutian. You've been very helpful, but I'm getting the same error as before, related to the line "Range("B1:B" & lastr).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)"

Comment: I'm still not sure why this happens, as it is working perfectly on my end. I have updated my answer with the "Slow" version (not using arrays), this might take a couple of minutes to run unlike the other version which could be instant. But it will do the same thing. Please don't click on anything while it runs.

Comment: When I run the second function, nothing happens. I have update the original question with two complete lines from the file. Maybe there's something in there that you can see is preventing the functions from working. Note, I'm using Excel 2007.

Comment: *When I run the second function, nothing happens* Can you check column B? It will have pasted one column over, and might be behind your current data. If there is nothing there, you could instead of pressing "F5", press "F8" a couple of times instead. This will execute the code line by line. You could check if it is executing the loop correctly (multiple times, instead of just skipping it in one go).

Comment: Oh yeah, column b has the corrected data. It's perfect. Thank you so much! I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: We got there eventually. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in Excel itself by using fairly simple formula without any VBA.

In cell B1:

`=""""&SUBSTITUTE(A1," """,""" """,1)`

Copy down till last data row.